# Difference between PlainObjectBase and DenseBase in Eigen

Tags: templates, eigen

I am new at Eigen and while going through I came across Dense Base and PlainObjectBase. But I don't understand what is the difference between them. What is the difference of Using DenseBase instead of PlainBaseObject

Answer (score 3):

`PlainObjectBase` is essentially just the base class for `Matrix` and `Array`, i.e., objects which actually store coefficients.

`PlainObjectBase` inherits from either `MatrixBase` or `ArrayBase` (depending on the template argument of `PlainObjectBase`). `MatrixBase` and `ArrayBase` are the common base classes for plain matrices/arrays as well as matrix/array-expressions.

Finally, `DenseBase` is the common base class of `MatrixBase` and `ArrayBase`.

This is documented here: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicClassHierarchy.html

Comment: so if we are using denseBase instead of PlainObjectBase is the code correct?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do.